# Extender control 'HtmlEditorExtender1' is not a registered extender control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, itext, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a webform on which I have used ajax toolkit's `HtmlEditorExtender1`. It's working fine. Now I am trying to convert entire webform into pdf using iTextSharp on a button click. But I am getting this error:

```
Extender control 'HtmlEditorExtender1' is not a registered extender control. Extender controls must be registered using RegisterExtenderControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors().
Parameter name: extenderControl
```

I believe it has something to do with the `HtmlEditorExtender1`

```
 <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtkeyresultforyear" EnableSanitization="false" />
```

**The top of my webform looks like this:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ModuleMain.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    ValidateRequest="false" CodeBehind="xyz.aspx.cs" EnableEventValidation = "false" Inherits="abc.xyz" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

**This my code on button click:**

```
protected void btntopdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

**EDIT:**

I am getting this error at :

```
this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>` in asp.net web form

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash in the master page , yes.

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash I just checked.. I cant find scriptmanager neither on master page nor the child page.. I tried adding script manager to the child page but then i got error that only one instance of scriptmanager can be added. Its strange.

Comment: Try add ScriptManager at just top of `</form>` of master page

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash I looked more thoroughly and found that my page inherits from a master page and that master page inherits from another master page.  The master page's master page has scriptmanager.

Comment: Not related to your problem but remove the line `Response.Write(pdfDoc);` because it does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I will remove anything you want me to... just please  see if you can get this working.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with your problem, I just know that that line will eventually produce corrupt PDF and should be removed.

Comment: @ChrisHaas i will keep that in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you pdf is generated correclty

then try this code

```
        pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
        pdfDoc.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition:", "attachment;filename=" + _fileName + ".pdf");
        //  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdfDoc);
```

to save to pdf.